# C++ client server Console Application error

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, networking

I am new with c++ and i was working with this guy code [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM7lzu960hM) . he makes an console socket application and connects with telnet which seems to work in his video.

when i try the same i get infinite loop and if() condition after for loop at bottom also dosenot work. Hopefully you guys can help me out with this.

```
//clientserver.h
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <conio.h>               //for getche()
#include <stdio.h>

#include <winSock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
```

clientserver.cpp

```
#include "clientserver.h"

using namespace std;

void main(){   


    long  answer;
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion;
    DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    answer = WSAStartup(DLLVersion,&wsaData);

      SOCKADDR_IN addr;  

    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    SOCKET sListen;
    SOCKET sConnect;


    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //was missing

    addr.sin_port = htons(8989);
    sListen = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
    //the socket becomes the structure "addr" 
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    //now we have to say that the socket is listening for an incoming connection.

    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);
    for(;;){
        cout << "waiting for connection" << endl;

        if (sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)){

                cout << "socket found a connection" << endl;
//cin >> ab101;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you also have a propery client-side code (someone that actually connects)? That the loop is infinite is ok, you are actually telling it to do so by not specifying a break-condition within your for(). If you are new to C++ you should really get the language basics right first before doing something more elaborate than networking, just an advice.

Comment: here is the code for client-side
http://pastebin.com/QFT8DM5z

Comment: If you changed your original post to have the answer incorporated, please add a quick comment to the post itself that you did so, and accept the answer that helped you fixed the issue. Otherwise people think that the question is unanswered and try to fix your (already corrected) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please REMOVE the `==` again if you did this, and leave it with the `sConnect = accept()`, just one equality sign.

Then add the marked line to your code:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // <----- THIS ONE RIGHT HERE!
addr.sin_port = htons(8989);
sListen = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
```

Previously you have created your socket with the IPv4 address family:

```
sConnect = socket(AF_INET,  SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
```

and I assume the call to `bind()` fails later on because you didn't specify which address family to use in your `SOCKADDR_IN`. If they don't match and the socket could not be bound, then the `accept()` doesn't actually listen to anything but returns an error code.

I tried your client and server code on my machine and at least there this was the problem. Please try adding the above line to your code and let us know if it helped. And please don't forget to change the `==` to a `=` as it was in your original post!

Comment: yeah i was missing this line 
'addr.sin_family = AF_INET;'
thanks alot, now it works.

Comment: Also, you can remove the `sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);`, it doesn't do anything but confuse someone reading your code. This variable will be re-assigned by the `accept()` anyways.